# Merge preceding partition with main partition ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I have unallocated space preceding the primary partition (shown in the image below)
[image: GParted view]

I want to merge that onto the /dev/nvme0n1p3. I searched alot but couldn't find a solution. Is there a way to achieve this without losing data on the /dev/nvme0n1p3
Thanks

Comment: Basically, backup, drag your root partition left into the unallocated space, then expand it on the right -- all from an install media since active partitions cannot be so treated.

Comment: In GParted select the /dev/nvme0n1p3 partition with a right click. Select Resize/Move and stretch the partition to the left. Click the green check mark to complete.